# Effective java item 32 issues : Type erasure is not working?

Tags: java

There is code in item32 in effective java

```java
public class Item32 {

    static <T> T[] toArray(T ... args){
        return args;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] attributes = toArray("1","2","3"); // no problem in Java 17 but problem in Java8
    }
}
```

As there is type erasure, I expect that result of `toArray("1","2","3")` is `Object[]`, so there is a `ClassCastException`. However, there is no exception for Java 17 and 11. But in Java 8, there is an exception. What happens in Java 17?

Comment: Tested with Java 8/9/10/11 and this is just a warning from the compiler, but not an Exception. The warning is "uses unchecked or unsafe operations". The warning goes away with Java 17.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with type erasure. I think it's just a matter of type inference.

Comment: I checked Effective Java Item 32 and there is only an exception when you also add the pickTwo method, because this causes the problem. This still happens with Java 8 and 17, so nothing changed. Maybe check the chapter again and correct the question, if you want to know about the Classcast exception or about the compiler warning which disapears with java 17.

Answer (score 3):

Type erasure is working here, it's just hard to see. It's also slightly complicated by the fact that arrays can have real subtypes: `String[]` is something you can check for a runtime.

Let's break down the elements here:

1. The `toArray` method is indeed type-erased, and so the `String[] attributes =` introduces an implicit cast (as always happens with type erasure).
2. However, when the call site infers at compile-time that this particular invocation has `T` being a `String`, it creates the array as a `String[]` — which is a subtype of `Object[]`.
3. It then passes that to `toArray`, which treats it only as an `Object[]` and returns it back.
4. Back at the call site, the type erasure forces that implicit cast to `String[]`, which succeeds due to how the call site created the array to begin with.

You would presumably not be surprised by something like this:

```
public static <T> T echo(T item) {
    return item;
}

Long i = echo(1L);
```

And you might further not be surprised if that call site were instead:

```
String[] a = echo(new String[0]);
```

The same thing is happening in your code.

You can see this if you use `javap -c` to look look at the bytecode. The relevant part is the end of the `main` method:

```
  34: invokestatic  #9    // Method toArray:([Ljava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object;
  37: checkcast     #10   // class "[Ljava/lang/String;"
  40: astore_2
  41: return
```

Answer (score 1):

In Effective Java (Third Edition) Item 32 it says below the definition of the `toArray` method:

> The type of this array is determined by the compile-time types of the arguments passed in to the method [...]

This is also what you are seeing; you are calling the method with three `String`s and therefore a `String[]` is created.

This behavior is described as well in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2); unfortunately it just refers to the "formal parameter [of a method]", while it actually seems to mean the inferred type, in your case `String[]`.

You are right that type erasure applies and the `T` of `toArray` is `Object` at runtime. However, because the array storing the arguments is implicitly created by the caller (as described above), the array has the type which was inferred at compile-time.

Most likely the `ClassCastException` occurred when you modified the code so that at compile time the argument of `T` could not be inferred as `String` anymore. As [pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72534097/effective-java-item-32-issues-type-erasure-is-not-working#comment128134821_72534097), in the code sample from Effective Java this occurs when another generic method named `pickTwo` is added which calls `toArray`.

In case you really experience a `ClassCastException` with exactly the code snippet you included in your question, it would be good if you shared information about the compiler you are using because that compiler might then have a bug.